# Аналог $query->is_main_query() для произвольного цикла

Tags: php, wordpress

Подскажите, как можно из хука pre_get_post добавить в произвольный цикл какое-то действие?
Произвольных циклов может быть много на странице, нужно определить нужный, и сделать обработчик в файле functions.php

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Изменение главного цикла](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/657023/%d0%98%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0)

Comment: @KAGG Design, при чём здесь дубликат? В этой теме вопрос про произвольные циклы, в той теме вопрос про стандартный цикл!
Это совсем разные вопросы

Comment: хуку pre_get_posts фиолетово, на какой цикл реагировать

Comment: >хуку pre_get_posts фиолетово, на какой цикл реагировать

Comment: >Произвольных циклов может быть много на странице, нужно определить нужный, и сделать обработчик в файле functions.php

Comment: вопрос был в том, как различить эти произвольные циклы этим, как вы говорите "фиолетовым pre_get_post"

Comment: как различить - анализировать аргумент $query, больше никак

Comment: ну и как проанализировать, чтобы различить разные произвольные циклы?

Comment: есть ли идеи, как это реализовать?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57571/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-word).